# Meaning of backtick in floating-point literal

Tags: numerics, syntax, arbitrary-precision, machine-precision

If I compute, say, `1/3//N`, *Mathematica* displays

```
0.333333
```

as the result.
When I copy that output to use elsewhere,
the paste produces

```
0.3333333333333333`
```

What is the meaning and function of the backtick ?

I realize this must be quite elementary.  I stand ready to be educated. :-)

Comment: See also [(26772)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/26772/121) for other appearances of the backtick, e.g. ``Developer`PartitionMap``

Answer (score 35, accepted):

The backtick is a short-hand to mark the precision of your output. If it is not followed by any number, it denotes machine precision. You can denote arbitrary precision by including a number, as for example, `` 0.3`20 ``.

By default, these are not displayed in `StandardForm`, which is why you see them only when copying, at which point it gets converted to `InputForm`. You can show them with `NumberMarks -> True`. For example:

```
Sqrt[2] // N
(* 1.4142135623730951 *)

InputForm[Sqrt[2] // N, NumberMarks -> True]
(* 1.4142135623730951` *)
```

Comment: InputForm? You mean StandardForm, isn't it?

Comment: @SjoerdC.deVries Yes, `StandardForm` for the first half of the sentence. However, when editing the cell/copy pasting, it gets converted to `InputForm` (with `NumberMarks -> True`).

Answer (score 31):

The default value of

```
$NumberMarks
```

> ```
> Automatic
> ```

means that ` should by default be used in arbitrary-precision but not machine-precision numbers. Arbitrary-precision numbers can contain an arbitrary number of digits e.g. :

```
Sqrt[3`21] == 1.73205080756887729353
```

Machine numbers contain the same number of digits and maintain no information on their precision, e.g. :

```
{Sqrt[3`10] == Sqrt[3] // N, Sqrt[3`10]}
```

> ```
> {True, 1.7320508076}
> ```

One can force machine numbers to be shown with number marks by :

```
Block[{$NumberMarks = True}, ToString[N[1/3], InputForm]]
```

> ```
> 0.3333333333333333`
> ```

`Precision[x]` yields the effective number of digits of precision in the number `x`.

```
Precision /@ {1/3, 1/3 // N}
```

[image]

```
Precision[1/3 // N] // N
```

> ```
> 15.9546
> ```

```
Round[MachinePrecision]
```

> ```
> 16
> ```

You can count the number of digits before the backtick, namely `16`.
 The `MachinePrecission` is a real number because on the hardware level it is represented in the binary form. This needs `53` bits to represent almost `16` digits :

```
N@{MachinePrecision*Log[2, 10], MachinePrecision}
```

> ```
> {53., 15.9546}
> ```

Comment: Thank you!  Strange that one needs to round MachinePrecision to see its value.

Comment: @Joseph `MachinePrecision` is a symbolic constant like `Pi` and `E`.  You can see its value using `N[MachinePresicion]` as well. This is what Artes did with `Precision[1/3 // N] // N
`.  Rounding gives the approximate (integer) number of digits of precision it corresponds to.

Comment: @Szaboics: Thanks, that makes sense!

Comment: This is indeed a very educational answer, Artes---Thanks!

Comment: You are welcome, I'm glad I could help.

Comment: No need to numerically evaluate `MachinePrecision`. `$MachinePrecision` serves that purpose.                 `In[14]:= $MachinePrecision === N[MachinePrecision]

Out[14]= True`

Comment: @DanielLichtblau I have rather different observation : `MachinePrecision === N[MachinePrecision]` yields `False` while `MachinePrecision == N[MachinePrecision]` yields `True`. The same with `E` and `Pi`.

Comment: @Artes Oops. I had typed `$MachinePrecision`. That dollar signs, apparently get munged. I might have caught it in a response. But not a comment, as they don't show what the result will look like.

Comment: Very helpful. A related question. Suppose I copy output and want to paste it somewhere WITHOUT the backticks. What is the best way?

Comment: @PaulCommentary Programatically one can find many ways and I'm not going to list them all, I recommend doing it manually: press `ctrl+f` write the bactick in the window `find` and in the window `replace` don't write anything then continue pressing `replace and find next`  until you complete your task.