# Relative error plot

Tags: plotting, approximation

I was plotting the relative error of the $e^{11/12 -n}n^{n+1/2}$ approximation to $n!$ as $n$ gets larger and larger, and at some very large value of $n$ *Mathematica* gives this plot:

[image]

Can somebody explain what exactly the plot means? Of course, I understand that, for larger and larger $n$, the relative error tends to a limit, but I am not sure how to interpret this plot. In particular, I don't understand how the error can show greater variation as $n$ grows large.

Thanks.

Edit: I want to add that when $n$ is an order of magnitude less what I get is something like this:

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/5zK7i.png]

Comment: This sounds more like a math question to me. Are you asking why it levels off as n grows larger?

Comment: Similar questions: http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/10820/replaceall-and-limit-dont-give-correct-results-for-this-expression-under-ex

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like numerical error, try increasing the `WorkingPrecision`

```
Plot[Abs[(Exp[11/12 - n] n^(n + 1/2) - n!)/n!]
   ,{n, 10, 10^7}
   ,WorkingPrecision -> 100]
```

[image: plot]

[WorkingPrecision is an option for various numerical operations that specifies how many digits of precision should be maintained in internal computations.](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/WorkingPrecision.html)

**Edit** You might also find `Limit` interesting

```
Limit[(Exp[11/12 - n] n^(n + 1/2) - n!)/n!, n -> Infinity]
N[%,50]
(* -1 + E^(11/12)/Sqrt[2 \[Pi]] *)
(* -0.0022692878024401615486447545367879811325821284314703  *)
```