# singularity in NDSolve for some values of parameter

Tags: differential-equations, numerical-integration, numerics

my equation is:

```
k[a_?NumericQ, b_?NumericQ, c_?NumericQ] := NDSolve[{r^3 b x''[r] y[r] - 12 x[r] y[r] - 
 4 r^3 b y''[r] x[r] == 0, 4 (2 x'[r]^2 + 
    2 x[r]x''[r])/Sqrt[c] + (2 y'[r]^2 + 
    2 y[r] y''[r])/Sqrt[c] == -4b/r,x[1] == 0, y[1] == Sqrt[-4 b Log[2/b]/(c^(-1/2))],
y'[1] == c^(1/4) (-4 b - 4 b Log[2 /b])/(2 Sqrt[-4 b Log[2/b] ] ), x'[1] == a},
 {x, y}, {r, 1, b/2}, MaxSteps -> 1000000]
```

and then I plot it:

```
Plot[Evaluate[{x[r], y[r]} /. k[1, 50, 10^(-7)]], {r, 1, 25}]
```

[image]

this one is okay, cause `x[r]` and `y[r]` both equal to 0 at `r=b/2`

if I set `a=0` and the other parameters stay the same

[image]

I do not know how comes this sigularity at `r=b/2`, basing on the second equation in NDSolve, `4 (2 x'[r]^2 + 
        2 x[r]x''[r])/Sqrt[c] + (2 y'[r]^2 + 
        2 y[r] y''[r])/Sqrt[c] == -4b/r` comes from the second derivative of `r` in this equation:

`c^(-1/2) 4 x[r]^2 + c^(-1/2) y[r]^2 == -4 r b Log[(2 r)/b]`

so it's easy to check, if `x[r]=0` all the way, `y[r]` should be `0` at `r=b/2`

does anyone know how to resolve the infinity at `r=b/2` for any values of the parameter?
`a>=0, b>2, 10^(-3)>c>10^(-7)`

thanks a lot

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think this is just another story of `WorkingPrecision`, let's try a higher one, say, `32`:

```
k[a_?NumericQ, b_?NumericQ, c_?NumericQ] := 
 NDSolve[{r^3 b x''[r] y[r] - 12 x[r] y[r] - 4 r^3 b y''[r] x[r] == 0,
    4 (2 x'[r]^2 + 2 x[r] x''[r])/
       Sqrt[c] + (2 y'[r]^2 + 2 y[r] y''[r])/Sqrt[c] == -4 b/r, 
   x[1] == 0, y[1] == Sqrt[-4 b Log[2/b]/(c^(-1/2))], 
   y'[1] == c^(1/4) (-4 b - 4 b Log[2/b])/(2 Sqrt[-4 b Log[2/b]]), 
   x'[1] == a}, {x, y}, {r, 1, b/2}, WorkingPrecision -> 32]

Plot[Evaluate[{x[r], y[r]} /. k[0, 50, 10^(-7)]], {r, 1, 25}]
```

[image]

OK, the singularity disappears.

Comment: yes, it works. can you explain more to me why this works? thanks

Comment: @3c. Well, to be honest, I'm not able to tell the exact reason, but based on my experience, if the plot of a function becomes unusual(singularity, hard oscillation etc while the function should not possess these features) in a point or in a small interval, it's often related to a `WorkingPrecision` that isn't high enough. There're numbers of posts about `WorkingPrecision` in this site, e.g. [this](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/10820/replaceall-and-limit-dont-give-correct-results-for-this-expression-under-ex), you can have a search for more details.