# What does ` symbol in ClearAll["Global`*"] mean?

Tags: syntax

I have found [an example](http://forums.wolfram.com/mathgroup/archive/1995/Jul/msg00058.html) for clearing all symbol definition by:

```
ClearAll["Global`*"]
```

But what does the symbol ` mean? It isn't the apostrophe ', yet it is not documented in *Mathematica* help.

Jim

Comment: It's a backtick. See [this](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/tutorial/Contexts.html).

Comment: It's related to the concept of `Context` in Mathematica, see [this](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/tutorial/Contexts.html).

Comment: @0x4A4D you are so fast!

Comment: You can learn a bit about the symbol ` in a different context than `Context`,  see this: [Meaning of backtick in floating-point literal](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/2915/meaning-of-backtick-in-floating-point-literal)

Comment: Thanks, this is solved. How can I mark one of the comments as an answer?

Answer (score 17):

In *Mathematica*, the back-tick or grave accent ( ` ) is used for two purposes:

1. As a *context mark* to delimit contexts (name spaces) in the full name of a variable.

   - [Tutorial: Contexts](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/Contexts.html)
2. As a *number mark* to mark the end of an approximate number, and separate the number from its precision value.

   - [`NumberMarks`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/NumberMarks.html)
   - [Tutorial: Numerical Precision](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/NumericalPrecision.html)

Comment: and what does that `*` symbol mean? I see in the [documentation](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ClearAll.html?q=ClearAll) that it is used just in the [Generalization & Extensions part](http://i.stack.imgur.com/4tKUb.png). But I couldn't find the documentation about it?

Comment: I'm guessing your are asking about the * in ``ClearAll["Global`*"]``. That * means zero-or-more-characters. It is documented [here](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/SomeGeneralNotationsAndConventions.html) under Abbreviated String Patterns. BTW, posting your question as a comment to my answer is most inappropriate. It has nothing to do with my answer and nothing to do with the original question. In the future, please keep your posts on-topic.

Comment: ok, I thought it will be a duplicate if I post a new one!

Comment: @m_goldberg though to be fair, the question was about what ` means in the command `ClearAll["Global\`*"]`, and your answer mentioned the meanings of ` in general but did not discuss its use in this context.