# Meaning of backtick in conjunction with units

Tags: syntax, units, precision-and-accuracy

In this fragment from an equation solution the backtick is used twice:

```
inputs = {HoldForm[
    Solve[Quantity[2.2`*^12, "Joules"] == 
      1/2 (Quantity[68000.`, "Kilograms"])*v^2, v]],
```

I thought the backtick was used to make context variables? Is it supposed to be a precision marker or something? Does 2.2` mean "I want the answer only in one decimal place"? I don't understand how/why the backtick is being used here.

Comment: @m_goldberg I read that post. It does not answer my question.

Comment: Why not? What you show is a number mark.

Comment: First of all the question is different (obviously). In the one answer the most relevant thing says "As a number mark to mark the end of an approximate number, and separate the number from its precision value." There are no precision values in the expression above, so I am no closer to understanding why the backtick is being used.

Comment: @m_goldberg probably meant [this Q/A](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/2915/125)...

Comment: @kguler. That is a better choice for "duplicate of" than the question I chose.