# Relevant help page for: Sum`?

Tags: functions, symbolic, summation, contexts, built-in-symbols

When I type `Sum` into Mathematica, it also offers `` Sum` `` in the autocomplete dropdown, but when I click the little menu button next to `` Sum` `` it doesn't take me to any help page.  I was hoping this was how to create symbolic sums for manipulation, but when I tried to use it, it turned the text `Sum` red (instead of the usual black for recognized functions), and I had to restart the kernel before things worked again.

I've read questions such as [Meaning of backtick in floating-point literal](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/2915/meaning-of-backtick-in-floating-point-literal), but I can't find any reference to how the backtick is used with functions.

What is the meaning of `` Sum` `` or what is the help file that explains it?

Comment: See http://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/Contexts.html

Comment: So ``Sum` `` is a context for ... for variables?

Comment: It's a context for functions internally used by `Sum`.  It's unlikely any them have documentation.  Try ``?Sum`*``

Answer (score 10, accepted):

To elaborate a bit on Michael's comment, let's first consider [this statement from the docs](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/SomeNotesOnInternalImplementation.html#894602702):

> `Sum` and `Product` use over 100 pages of Wolfram Language code.

Executing `` ?Sum`* `` will in fact show you some of the internal routines used behind the scenes by the function `Sum[]`. You, the regular user, are not usually intended to access these by yourself; however, if you look at the names of some of these, you'll see some correspondence with the [list of `Method`s supported by `Sum[]`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Sum.html#220030).

So, for instance,

```
Sum[i^2, i, Method -> "Polynomial"]
```

will at some point call

```
Sum`SumPolynomialFunction[i^2, i]
```

P.S. there is also a `` Product` `` context.