# The ` in Solve results

Tags: equation-solving

I assign the result of a Solve to the variable eq8. Then I attempt to use this result in the definition of a function as follows:

```
In[166]:= eq8 = Solve[eq7, {V1}]
Out[166]= {{V1 -> -1.02 (461.185 - 1. im)}}
In[177]:= Vstrom = eq8[[1, 1, 2]]
Out[177]= -1.02 (461.185 - 1. im)
current[im_] := N[Vstrom]
```

This does not work. With copy of Out[177] and paste it - instead of Vstrom - into N[] I find

```
current[im_] := N[-1.0200000000000002` (461.184642121376` - 1.` im)]
```

When eliminating these `characters, my function works. Why can't I use the notation N[Vstrom]? After all, these`-characters in the above number are just the spec. that the number shall have maschine accuracy. So why does the funktion not work with these characters present?

Comment: This is related [Meaning of backtick in floating-point literal](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/2915/meaning-of-backtick-in-floating-point-literal).

Comment: I have joined another user in voting to close this as a duplicate.  Please read the Q&A linked in the banner at the top of your post.  If this does not solve your problem please edit your question to describe exactly how your situation is different.

Comment: Set `$NumberMarks = False` if the backticks annoy you.

Comment: I think the question here is "Why can't I use the notation `N[Vstrom]`", not about tick notation. The problem here is `current[im_] := N[Vstrom]`, where the expectation was that `im` would get replaced. But with `:=`, the RHS isn't evaluated, so `im` doesn't appear. Use `current[im_] = N[Vstrom]` instead.