# Copy-pasting a floating point number

Tags: front-end, numerics, number-representation

Here is a behavior of the Mathematica front end which confuses me. Type

```
N[Sqrt[2]]
```

The displayed output is

```
1.41421
```

Highlight that number with the mouse, copy it to the clipboard and then paste it on a newline within the notebook. You'll get

```
1.4142135623730951`
```

After this, continue typing to produce

```
1.4142135623730951`+1
```

Evaluate this, and you get

```
1.
```

By trial and error, I have learned that I get the right answer by deleting the back-quote:

```
1.4142135623730951 + 1
```

evaluates to

```
2.41421
```

Why? What does the back-quote mean internally?

Comment: Have you seen [this](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/2915)?

Comment: Simply add a space after the `