# output has a term uncomputed

Tags: list-manipulation

I am trying to sum the all numbers in each row of matrix and divide them by the max value of the row. My output has the following terms that has not been computed yet (example, the second element in the list)

```
{0.274667, 6.70453 (0.0361427 + 0.00173611 ""), 1., 0.497337, 0.329659, 0.330391, 0.532257, 0.385172, 0.0139678, 0.403161, 0.0507919, 0.520617, 0.385253,    0.0902533, 6.70453 (0.0629163 + 0.0014881 ""), 0.478209,6.70453 (0.0268595 + 0.00189394 ""), 0.486349, 0., 6.70453 (0.0399427 + 0.00173611 ""), 0
```

when I copied the uncomputed term and pasted in a new notebook, it looked like this

```
6.70452801227936` (0.03614267676767676` + 0.001736111111111111` "")
```

Can anyone tell me what is the special character after the number ' ` 'doing here ?

Comment: Re: backtick, see [this](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/2915). For "sum the all numbers in each row of matrix and divide them by the max value of the row": `Total[#]/Max[#] & /@ matrix`.

Comment: And it looks like there are hidden `String`s (i.e. `""`) in your code somewhere.

Comment: @J.M.: Thank you for that, I am going to recode my program

Comment: @march: how do I remove the hidden strings? the data is from csv file

Comment: expression /. ""->Sequence[] turns all the "" in expression into nothing.