# Mathematics arbitrary precision evaluation

Tags: arbitrary-precision

I am trying to solve a simple expression:

[image: sample expression]
where `a = 77617`, and `b = 33096`.

Wolfram|Alpha returns a correct result, using following form:

```
a = 77617, b = 33096, 
c = (333.75 - a^2) * b^6 + a^2 * (11 * a^2 * b^2 - 121 * b^4 - 2) + 5.5 * b^8 + a/(2.0 * b)
```

> `-54767/66192`

which is approximately -0.827396.

Mathematica, when I evaluate the following code:

```
ClearAll[a, b, c]
a = N[77617, 128];
b = N[33096, 128];
N[(333.75 - a^2)*b^6 + a^2*(11*a^2*b^2 - 121*b^4 - 2) + 5.5*b^8 + a/(
  2.0*b), 128]
```

returns 0.

Could you please to point how to get a correct result using Mathematica?

Comment: For starters, use `11/2` and `1335/4` instead of `5.5` and `333.75`.

Comment: @J.M. (1335/4 - a^2)*b^6 + a^2*(11*a^2*b^2 - 121*b^4 - 2) + 11/2*b^8 + a/(
 2.0*b) returns the same result, zero (with and without using N function).

Comment: I did not notice the `2.0`; replace that with just `2`. What you must know here is that numbers with decimal points and no precision indicators are *machine precision* numbers, which was why your original expression was not being evaluated to arbitrary precision.

Comment: Thank you so much! So, as I understand, to let Mathematica correctly evaluate expressions, all variables should have rational and integer types.

Comment: Well, yes, either use exact numbers, or if you really must have arbitrary-precision inexact numbers, use a [backtick](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/2915), e.g. ``5.5`128`` or ``2`128``.

Comment: See also: [(55292)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/55292/121)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In working with approximate numbers, it is important to ensure that no terms you introduce (e.g. 5.5 or 333.75) are lower precision than you need to work to.

Wherever you have exact coefficients, it is good practice to specify these as rational to avoid this problem.

The particular problem you have here is that the terms in b^6 and b^8 are almost equal in magnitude but opposite in sign, requiring high precision to evaluate the result without catastrophic loss of precision.

We can investigate the behaviour with the following code

```
values[n_] := N[{a -> 77617, b -> 33096}, n];
c = (333 + 3/4 - a^2)*b^6 + a^2*(11*a^2*b^2 - 121*b^4 - 2) +  11/2*b^8 + a/(2*b);
```

For example

```
c /. values[∞]
(* -(54767/66192) *)
c /. values[50]
(* -0.82739605995 *)
c/. values[30]
(* 0.*10^8 *)
```

Answer (score 1):

I would do it this way.

```
c = With[{a = 77617, b = 33096}, 
  Map[
    Rationalize, 
    Hold[(333.75 - a^2)*b^6 + a^2*(11*a^2*b^2 - 121*b^4 - 2) + 5.5*b^8 + a/(2.0*b)], 
    {-1}] // ReleaseHold]
```

> `-(54767/66192)`

I think this is likely to be pretty close to the way Wolfram|Alpha does it.

If you really want the result to 128 decimal places, you can now evaluate

```
 N[c, 128]
```

> `-0.8273960599468213681411650954798162919990331157843848199178148416727\
>   0969301426154218032390621223108532753202803964225284022238337`